# Nodejs EJS helper functions?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Is there a way to register helper functions to EJS templates, so that they can be called from any EJS template? So, it should work something like this.

app.js

```
ejs.helpers.sayHi = function(name) {
    return 'Hello ' + name;
});
```

index.ejs

```
<%= sayHi('Bob') %>
```

Comment: did this work with <%= ?

Comment: I made up `ejs.helpers` as an example of what I'm looking for, it doesn't exist. So it doesn't matter either way, but you're right I should probably switch it to `<%=`

Comment: Are filters out of the question?  They're helper-like and documented up front on the EJS github.  Your helper would translate to something like `<%= 'Bob' | sayHi %>` in the template.  The function would be written identically.

Comment: My apologies if you're not talking about visionmedia's ejs.  Jumping to conclusions over here.

Comment: I was trying to test if using filters would actually work, and allow me to pass multiple arguments. I suppose if I passed an object as the argument, that would work. It feels like a workaround though.

Comment: They do.  Just separate args with commas.  The parsing can get a little wonky though, if your arguments are complex, like objects.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, in Express 3 you can add helpers to `app.locals`. Ex:

```
app.locals.somevar = "hello world";

app.locals.someHelper = function(name) {
  return ("hello " + name);
}
```

These would be accessible inside your views like this:

```
<% somevar %>

<% someHelper('world') %>
```

Note: Express 2.5 did helpers differently.

Comment: And where do you write such code? A link would have been helpful.

Comment: You can write this code in the main application body, after doing var app = express();

Comment: Hum. I just don't have app, because it's overloaded by sails.js, and it's probably a bad idea to write that into the app.js, I would prefer to write this into another file called by the app.js

Comment: the middleware.js in the config folder gives you an indication of how to do it in https://github.com/stefanbuck/sails-social-auth-example. You could define it there

Comment: you can find a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/ajeeshpu/8908454) @Vadorequest for getting the current year based on my comment above.

Comment: @ajeeshpu Thanks! I'll take a better look into that, interesting!

Comment: I found that an equals was required to make the call in the .ejs document work: <%= someHelper('world') %>.

Comment: EDIT: it's working -- This is not working for me... it says `funcName is not defined`

Answer (score 23):

I have another solution to this, and I think it has some advantages:

- Don't polute your code exporting filters.
- Access any method without the need to export them all.
- Better ejs usage (no | pipes).

On your controller:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
// send your function to ejs
    res.render('index', { sayHi: sayHi });
}

function sayHi(name) {
    return 'Hello ' + name;
};
```

Now you can use sayHi function inside your ejs:

```
<html>
    <h1><%= sayHi('Nice Monkey!') %></h1>
</html>
```

You can use this method to send modules to ejs, for example, you could send 'moment' module to format or parse dates.

Comment: **+1** The only thing that helped solve my problem on this page was the `=` before the function `<%= sayHi() %>` otherwise it wouldn't print

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example filter...I'm not familiar with helpers.

```
var ejs = require('ejs');

ejs.filters.pluralize = function(num, str){
    return num == 1 ? str : str+'s';
};


 <%=: items.length | pluralize:'Item' %>
```

Will produce "Item" if it's 1, or if 0 or > 1, produces "Items"

app.js

```
ejs.filters.sayHi = function(name) {
    return 'Hello ' + name;
});
```

index.ejs

```
<%=: 'Bob' |  sayHi %>
```

Comment: FYI , this doesn't work anymore with EJS V2. Dilanized and Robertomarin works in both version.

Answer (score 4):

I am using:

In helpers/helper.js

```
var func = {
    sayhi: function(name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }, 
    foo: function(date) {
        //do somethings
    }    
};
module.exports = func;
```

In router:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('home/index', {
        helper: require('../helpers/helper'),
        title: 'Express'
    });
});
```

In template:

```
<%= helper.sayhi("Dung Vu") %>
```

goodluck