# Redirect to a specific link routing

Tags: node.js, express

i'm using express to make a electronic document management (EDMS) in node.js.

After the user login, I'll have a simple box, where he's chosee between two options:
a. search XML files
b. search Other Documents files

is there a way to create specific routing for, if he chooses to go only with XML, all links i'll be under that routing?

Something like `xml/home/` and `otherDocuments/home/` and the rest of the methods ill be `xml/something` and `otherDocuments/something`?

Comment: Do you mean you want your router in express to handle the prefix for you? `const router = express.Router(); router.get('/foo', /**/); app.use('/xml', router);` - now the /foo handler is reached via `/xml/foo`.

Comment: or do you mean that you want the actual `<a>` hrefs in the HTML side to be prefixed with the specific path?

Comment: or do you just mean that you want `res.redirect()` to get the prefix for you?

Comment: I mean that my router handle the prefix, once the xml visualization is selected, all the links will be redirect/prefix to a ```xml/foo```, or if otherDocs is selected, all the links will be to ```otherDocs/foo```, based on the first selection after login

Comment: What are you using to generate the HTML?

Comment: i'm using EJS, so that i can manipulate it better with JS :)

Comment: You could pass a helper function to your EJS views which generates the links. You'd define this function in the controller/router and that is the function that adds the prefix to the links. See [_Nodejs EJS helper functions?_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18501016/996081).

Comment: I'll take a look on that, I think it's what I need, thank @cubrr