# Creating and using ejs helper functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to add helper functions to my ejs templates. I have followed the answers provided in the link [nodejs ejs helper functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221760/nodejs-ejs-helper-functions). However it doesn't seem to work. All other properties from the `ViewModel` object appears except for the timestamp property, which is passed to the timestamp function in `app.locals`.

**The object being rendered to the main template**

```
const ViewModel = {
    image:{
        uniqueId: 1,
        title: 'Sample Image 1',
        description: 'This is a sample.',
        filename: 'sample1.jpg',
        Views: 0,
        likes: 0,
        timestamp: Date.now()
},
```

**helpers/timeago.js**

```
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = (timestamp) => {
        return moment(timestamp).startOf('minute').fromNow();
}
```

**Relevant code from server.js**

```
const helpers = require('./helpers');
helpers(app);
```

**helper.js Putting the function into app.locals**

```
const timeago = require('./../helpers/timeago');

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.locals.timeago = timeago;
};
```

**Main.ejs template: Using the function in app.locals**

```
<em class="text-muted"><% timeago(image.timestamp) %></em>
```

How do I successfully add functions to app.locals and use them in an ejs template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use functions in EJS template rendering. Your problem is likely that you are using the flow control tag `<%` instead of an output tag, `<%-` or `<%=`.

So your template should probably contain:

```
<em class="text-muted"><%- timeago(image.timestamp) %></em>
```